# Get the recently Changed Documents without Search-Driven webparts

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using SPO and I wanted to know if Is it possible to get the recently changed documents of a site collection without using the search-driven webparts? With javascript or something like that?

Comment: what is the scope? All documents in a list, web, or site collection?

Comment: A site collection

Comment: check out marc's xsl template for a DVWP that does this: http://sympmarc.com/2013/06/05/displaying-the-most-recent-documents-from-all-document-libraries-in-a-sharepoint-site/

Comment: Is there a way to get that result with js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tap into Search using the REST API. You would need to parse out the most recent documents of the site, and make sure they are of the filetype, docx, xlsx, pptx, pdf, etc..

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nadeemis/archive/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api.aspx

Comment: Search is also best for performance, if one can live with the delay